# jQuery validate some dynamic loaded radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This project is using attendance registers, they are required to chart the behaviour and progress of students on a scale of 1-4, upon selection a script is called and a list of relevant comments are created. If the teacher marks 2 or less the the radio button has a class mandatory, the returned code is as follows:

```
<table class="comment-list">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[123456]" value="25" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Work not always on time</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[123456]" value="26" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Has some difficulties with coursework</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[123456]" value="27" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Assessment failed</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[123456]" value="28" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Standard of work unacceptable</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Another table on the same page may look like

```
<table class="comment-list">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[444555]" value="25" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Work not always on time</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[444555]" value="26" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Has some difficulties with coursework</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[444555]" value="27" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Assessment failed</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="progresscomment[444555]" value="28" class="mandatory"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Standard of work unacceptable</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I know that ...

```
    $($('.mandatory').each(function() {).each(function(){
```

...will not work as if checks all the elements of the same group.

There will be many of these tables on the page, the array key will be different for each table i.e. all the ones in the example are the same but another table else where on the page will have a different key. I want to make sure that at least one is checked in every group where the class is mandatory. I believe this might be able to be done using the name but I can't visualise the solution.

Thank you in advance for all your help

EDIT, I have managed to get close to a solution I need help with this final step.

The solution ended up using the id of the drop down in question to dynamically select the radio button group.

The JavaScript is as follows

```
    $( ".behaviour-sel" ).each(function( index ) {
     //check if empty
     if($(this).val() == ""){
      alert("You must enter behaviour for ALL students");
      return rv = false;
     }

     //check if it's less than 2
     if($(this).val() <= 2){     
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      id = id.replace('-behaviour', '');

      if(!$('input[name="behaviourcomment[' + id + ']"]').is(':checked')) { 
      alert("If you scored behaviour less than 2, you MUST select a supporting comment");
       return rv = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: You could use jQuery validate with the 'require from group' validator: https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/

Comment: Thanks, for responding, I will give it a try but I don't know how it will work without ID's considering they are radio buttons.

Comment: It'll work fine, just make sure you use the `name` attribute of the elements to group them, not the class.

Comment: Thanks I have managed to visualise a solution but I have a syntax error maybe you could help?

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=behaviourcomment[123456]]`

Comment: You need to put quotes around the attribute value in the selector, otherwise it gets confused with the nested square brackets: `input[name="behaviourcomment[123456]"]`

Comment: Thank you Rory, this is now working and will post in the main comment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up using the id of the drop down in question to dynamically select the radio button group.

The JavaScript is as follows

```
$( ".behaviour-sel" ).each(function( index ) {
 //check if empty
 if($(this).val() == ""){
  alert("You must enter behaviour for ALL students");
  return rv = false;
 }

 //check if it's less than 2
 if($(this).val() <= 2){     
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  id = id.replace('-behaviour', '');

  if(!$('input[name="behaviourcomment[' + id + ']"]').is(':checked')) { 
  alert("If you scored behaviour less than 2, you MUST select a supporting comment");
   return rv = false;
  }
}
```